# Multiple left joins and where clause with multiple values

Tags: mysql, join

I had lots of tables and had performed multiple join lefts all the tables without incorrect or duplicate results. One of my table is multi-values, can accept duplicate same ids. When I left joins all the tables, the result shows correct, but that particular column show one of the values from  multi-values table.

Currently I'm doing filtering the multi-values table, but the result is unforseen because it only output single one of the value from multi-values table.

**Menu Table**

```
id cuisine_id 
1  1
```

**CuisineMenu Table (Multi-values / Accept duplicated menu's id)**

```
cuisine_id menu_id
1          1   
2          2 (Ignore)
3          1
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM menu 
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT *      
       FROM cuisinemenu     
       GROUP BY menu_id 
) cuisinemenu ON cuisinemenu.menu_id = menu.id
WHERE ( cuisine_id = '3')
```

**Output**

**Without Where Clause**

```
id cuisine_id
1  1
```

**With Where Clause**

```
Empty
```

**Expected Result (With Where Clause)**

```
id cuisine_id
1  3
```

Comment: is this question related to mysql or Sql Server? If it is Sql Server then it must be WHERE ( cuisinemenu.cuisine_id = '3').

Comment: The empty result set is actually correct. The join condition `menu.id = cuisine_menu.cuisine_id` and the where clause `where cuisine_menu.id = 3` cannot co-exist. Please refine your requirements.

Comment: @YusufHassan that's cuisinemenu.menu_id = menu.id i hope. Not sure if this question pertains to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `LEFT JOIN`, try below:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Menu m LEFT JOIN CuisineMenu cm ON m.id = cm.menu.id
WHERE cm.cuisine_id = 3;
```

This should result in 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql code from following:

```
   SELECT *      
   FROM cuisinemenu     
   GROUP BY menu_id
```

to this:

```
   SELECT *      
   FROM cuisinemenu     
   GROUP BY cuisine_id
```

the first one shows only menu_id without showing the cuisine_id.